# Comparing the struct fields from two interfaces without knowing their type?

Tags: go

I'd like to write a function that accepts two arbitrary types via interface, looking for fields in common and comparing their values.

One is a struct that has been bound from JSON input, the other is derived from querying a database, specifically the latter are of types in the https://godoc.org/github.com/jackc/pgtype package - I've tried to simplify what I'm getting at in the example below:

```
package main



type Int4 struct {
    Int    int32
}

func (i Int4) Get() int32 {
  return i.Int
}

func (i Int4) Set(val int32) {
  i.Int = val
}

type Varchar struct {
    String    string
}

func (v Varchar) Get() string {
  return v.String
}

func (v Varchar) Set(val string) {
  v.String = val
}



type existing struct {
   ID Int4
   Foo Varchar
   Bar Int4
   Baz Varchar
}

type changes struct {
  Foo string
  Bar int32
  Baz string
}



func main() {
    var a existing
    a.ID.Set(1)
    a.Foo.Set("afoo")
    a.Bar.Set(123)
    a.Baz.Set("bazza")

    b := &changes{Foo: "bfoo", Bar: 321, Baz: "bazza"}

    compareModels(a, b)

}

// compareModels should compare two structs with inconsistent properties but some Field names in common.
func compareModels(existingState interface{}, newState interface{}){

    // desired output:
    // Foo is not equal
    // Bar is not equal
    // Baz is equal

}
```

Comment: Yes it is very much possible. If you need inspiration just use github's search, there's already a number of go packages that do that kind of thing with reflection.

Comment: There are packages out there (eg. github.com/google/go-cmp) which do this. Use one or take a look how it is done.

Comment: Also https://github.com/go-test/deep has some good examples of this.

Comment: sorry, my question was too simplified. I've updated it to include more detail.